# View Resolver configuration in case multi modular project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, model-view-controller, view

I have a Spring Boot project which consists of different modules.

```
Octava
|-Application
|-Business
|-Core
```

[image]

In the **Application** module, It has core SpringBoot application config
**Business** module has web config. So, in this structure, It encounters an error

```
2018-10-03 00:03:53 DEBUG JstlView:168 - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'index'
2018-10-03 00:03:53 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:891 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp]
2018-10-03 00:03:53 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:312 - Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/views/index.jsp
2018-10-03 00:03:53 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:322 - Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp]
2018-10-03 00:03:53 WARN  PageNotFound:1205 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-10-03 00:03:53 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:129 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@73a34264
2018-10-03 00:03:53 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1000 - Successfully completed request
```

Current ViewResolver config

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"controller", "service", "dao", "model", "exception"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class BusinessMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(500000000L);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
}
```

Also in Business module set up Spring Security which works fine. After authentification, I receive 404 error.

So, the question is how to set up View Resolver for this kind of structure?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the solution here [see topic 7.2](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-migration).

So, all I need:

- add thymeleaf dependency,

Gradle

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: '2.1.1.RELEASE'
```

- move all views webbapp folder to resources/templates folder,

[image]

If you want to change suffix and prefix for view resolver it can be reconfigured in application.properties in resource folder:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/WEB-INF/views/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.jsp
```

Full default spring boot properties can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)